# How to define models in Node-ORM2 in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

On Node-ORM Wiki there is shown example of defining models in JS, that looks like these:

```
var Person = db.define('person', {
  id      : { type: "serial", key: true }, // autoincrementing primary key
  name    : { type: "text" },
  surname : { type: "text" },
  age     : { type: "number" }
}, {
  methods : {
    fullName: function () {
      return this.name + " " + this.surname;
    }
  }
});
```

How should I do the same thing in TypeScript?

(I know there is orm module in TypeScript:
https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/blob/master/lib/TypeScript/orm.d.ts
I just don't know how to use it and there is no sample).

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. If you have JavaScript code to do something, the TypeScript code to do something is the same as the JavaScript code. What did you try?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh, I was trying to write strongly typed classes. I was assuming, that by using JS code, I would get class and all her database-related methods, but it wouldn't be strongly typed.